# How to get the contents of a .txt file into a string C#

Tags: c#

I have the file path of a txt file inside a string. How do I put the text of this file into another string?

Comment: Microsoft also has a [guide on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file). Searching ["C# read text file" on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+read+text+file) brings up a ton of results. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 2):

Use [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-6.0)

```
    var path = "[yourPathHere]";
    var contents = File.ReadAllText(path);
```